# Are there no threats and only benefits for using hyperbaric oxygen therapy?

Tags: brain, oxygen

Following [this story](http://www.nydailynews.com/life-style/health/toddler-brain-damage-reversed-drowned-article-1.3338812) and many others, I read articles that hyperbaric oxygen therapy can help people with brain damage but can also help healthy people. I heard that hyperbaric oxygen therapy can improve athletic performance as well as cognitive process of healthy people. Are there any proven research that shows this? Is it totally safe and has only benefits and no threats for healthy people? What is the minimum time for improving your brain and performance and does it last forever?

Comment: I think that hyperbaric oxygen therapy is the correct term you're looking for, not pressure cabinet.  I'd edit it to make sure people know what you're asking about.

Comment: @DoctorWhom FYI, anyone can edit posts. Until you have enough rep your edits will have to be approved, but you can still do it.

Comment: Ah thx, wasn't sure how that worked.

Answer (score 2):

While hyperbaric oxygen therapy does have many benefits, there are potential issues. According to John Hopkins University Hyperbaric oxygen therapy can lead to lung damage, fluid buildup in the ears and vision changes. While these are not common, they can occur from the high pressure that the body is experiencing. A healthy person without indications for its use may want to avoid it, but in reality they will likely be fine as long as the treatment isn't long and they don't have any contraindications for it.

link to John Hopkins article: http://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/healthlibrary/conditions/physical_medicine_and_rehabilitation/complications_of_hyperbaric_oxygen_treatment_134,148/